# Mock a protected method

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, model-view-controller, moq

I've looked through almost every link I can possibly find on google to do with this subject and have come up with two of the following solutions which do not run correctly. I have a protected method that simply returns a string.

```
protected virtual string ConfirmText
    {
        get
        {
            return "someTextHere";
        }
    }
```

This is in a viewmodel. My tests so far that I have tried are -

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Confirm_Text_test()
    {
        Mock<TestViewModel> testViewModel= new Mock<TestViewModel>(null, null, null);

        testViewModel.Protected()
            .Setup<string>("ConfirmText")
            .Returns("Ok")
            .Verifiable();


        testViewModel.Verify();
    }
```

I understand that with the above example I have only setup, and assert, not acted upon it. I haven't been able to find a way to act upon the set-up such as

```
var result = testViewModel.ConfirmText;
```

as it says it is inaccessible due to its protection level.

The next way I have tried is

```
var result = testViewModel.Object.GetType()
            .InvokeMember("ConfirmText",
             BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | 
             BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
             BindingFlags.Instance, 
             null, 
             testViewModel.Object, 
             null);
```

Am I missing something out, as most examples I've looked into show something similar to the first method I tried.

Comment: This is not a method, but a property.

Comment: I'm incredibly dumb at times. That will probably explain why nothing is working! I'll get back to looking, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Why would you want to mock a protected property? Usually you mock objects to control or verify the external calls to their methods/properties .. who is calling this and what are you trying to do with the mock?

Comment: The member calls to a resource dictionary, I'm just wanting to confirm that it's getting the correct text. As if somebody changes the text without knowing what it's for later down the line it might cause UX issues.

Comment: Right .. so, if I understand correctly, you don't really need a mock, you can just create an instance of `TestViewModel` and invoke the propery via reflection as you've done in the 2nd example

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: @DanielSims I think you should post your edit as an answer.

Comment: @haindl Have done, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment above posting this as an answer instead of an edit.

I solved this with the following advice from the above using reflection.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ConfirmText()
{
    TestViewModel testViewModel= new TestViewModel (null, null, null);

    var result = testViewModel.GetType()
    .InvokeMember("ConfirmText",
     BindingFlags.GetProperty |
     BindingFlags.NonPublic |
     BindingFlags.Instance,
     null,
     testViewModel,
     null);

    Assert.AreEqual("Confirm", result);
}
```

with the method being -

```
protected override string confirmText
{
    get
    {
        return Properties.Resources.confirmMessage;
    }
}
```